# Which rotation method should I use for factor analysis?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have a binary dataset including 120 participants and 92 questions. I used factor analysis using R which showed 22 factors and I wondered what kind of rotation method should I use in this situation? If it is possible to do rotation method in this case how should I do that in R?
I would appreciate your help with this,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is often done within the function that does the factor analysis. If you use e.g.  `psych::fa` there is an argument `rotate`. As long as you are a beginner and have not strong opinions on your rotations you can either stick to common choices such as oblimin oder varimax or you could try different options and see, if any produces a factor solution that lends itself to plausible interpretation.

From the man page of the above mentioned function a list of implemented rotations:

> "none", "varimax", "quartimax", "bentlerT", "equamax", "varimin", "geominT" and "bifactor" are orthogonal rotations. "Promax", "promax", "oblimin", "simplimax", "bentlerQ, "geominQ" and "biquartimin" and "cluster" are possible oblique transformations of the solution. The default is to do a oblimin transformation, although versions prior to 2009 defaulted to varimax.

(copied from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.1.6/topics/fa )